# Jquery Image Radio Buttons not switching

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a few radio buttons that are using images as the display on the screen. A regular state, a hover state and a clicked state.  The images are showing on every state, but if I click 2 radio button, both stay clicked. How can I have it be either or when clicked.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(".image_radiobtn input[type='radio']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $(this).next("label").removeClass('hover').addClass('checked');          
    }
    else{
       $(this).next("label").removeClass('checked');
    }
});
```

Here is the html:

```
         <ul id="radiobtn-toggle-view" class="image_radiobtn">
          <li>
           <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="address" value="1" /> 
           <label for="input-1">Use this address.</label>
          </li>
         </ul>
```

Here is the css:

```
#radiobtn-toggle-view, #radiobtn-toggle-view2 {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
}

#radiobtn-toggle-view li, #radiobtn-toggle-view2 li{
min-height: 15px;
height: 15px;
margin:0;
padding: 10px 0;  
}

#radiobtn-toggle-view label, #radiobtn-toggle-view2 label {
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 15px;
line-height: 15px;
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
}
.image_radiobtn li input[type='radio']{
display:none;
}

.image_radiobtn li label {
background: url(/images/icons/grey_radio_btn.png) no-repeat;
padding-left: 20px;
}

.image_radiobtn li label:hover { 
background: url(/images/icons/e_radio_btn.png) no-repeat;
}

.image_radiobtn li label.checked {
background: url(/images/icons/g_radio_btn.png) no-repeat;
}


.hidden {display: none;}
```

Comment: Do they all have the same `name` property/attribute? (They should, if they're mutually-exclusive.) But you're also not checking to remove the classes that you're adding, which I suspect is the actual problem.

Comment: try changing the if($(this).is(":checked")) to if($(this).val(":checked"))

Comment: nilzone - didn't work.

Comment: what do you mean David? Do you mean name="address". If so, for this case then yes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear all checked classes before adding a new one in your Jquery code.
PS: Change the selector according to you hierarchy, in a way that it gets all the radios on the group.

```
$(".image_radiobtn input[type='radio']").change(function(){
    $('selector').removeClass('checked');
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $(this).next("label").removeClass('hover').addClass('checked');          
    }
    else{
       $(this).next("label").removeClass('checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: madaaah - do you mean change the selector to the id or class that is in the html for the div or the ul?  i just tired your code and it didn't work for me.  i am guessing it is because i didn't change the selector.

Comment: I mean, use a selector that get ALL of your radio buttons that are of the same group... For example, if they are all inside that ul, try $('#radiobtn-toggle-view input[type='radio']').removeClass('checked');

Comment: But of course, remove the class from the same place where you add it.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work for me. 
    $(".image_radiobtn input[type='radio']").change(function(){  
    $('#radiobtn-toggle-view input[type='radio']').removeClass('checked'); 
     if($(this).is(":checked")){ 
     $(this).next("label").removeClass('hover').addClass('checked'); } 
    else{ $(this).next("label").removeClass('checked'); } });

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear enough. When the radio buttons are clicked, they work. They show clicked, but if I click the other one, it also stays clicked instead of unchecking the 1st radio button.

Comment: Anyone know why both the radio button stay clicked vs being either or?